# How to stop JS autoclick loop

Tags: javascript

I've made a script that auto-click a button on load. This button will add an item on cart and also make a pop-up. After you click the close pop-up icon, the page will be refreshed and triggering auto-click loop. Is there a way to bypass this?

my script:

```
var a = document.getElementById("discount");
if (discount.dataset.value === "TEST"){for ( var i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
  document.getElementById("clickMe").click();
}}
```

Comment: Use a variable to hold state and save it in persistent storage and then use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is working for you!

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('autoClick')) { // check if code already ran
  // if not then do the clicks

  var a = document.getElementById("discount");
  if (discount.dataset.value === "TEST"){for ( 
  var i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
    document.getElementById("clickMe").click();
  }}

  localStorage.setItem('autoClick', true); // save that you did the clicks
} else {
  // if you did the click and pop-up refreshed the page, 
  // let's remove the state so you can auto click again on next refresh
  localStorage.removeItem('autoClick'); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use *'break'* in you *'for loop'*.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break